Installing Python 3 on legacy MacOS (10.15 Catalina)
I am trying to update python on my MacBook Pro 2013, but I can’t seem to get anything to work. Brew and Macports both don’t support MacOS this far back and Xcode won’t update because it’s to old. Is this even possible? I’m considering trying to get a legacy version of brew to install, but if there is an easier way i would prefer that. Any help is appreciated.

MacPorts does support Catalina. See the install page

I must have faulty information then. I will look into this. Thanks for the tip!

Homebrew supports the same as Apple, current to current-2.  MacPorts supports all the way back to the PPC timeframe.  What python are you trying to "update"?  You don't need to replace the system python 2.x, leave it alone.  Just install what you want to use.  Multiple python installs can co-exist.

Just run the installer from python.org.

Turns out MacPorts does support MacOS Catalina. I just had bad info. This worked just fine. Turns out MacPorts has legacy .pkg installers which you can get from here: https://www.macports.org/install.php#installing (Thanks Allan for this link). Just download and run that, then use
sudo port install python312 

to get python 3.12 installed (the latest version at the time of writing). If you want to set it as default, simply enter this command:
sudo port select —-set python python312

Hope this helps!

Glad you’re able to get things working.  However, you may wish to include some links to the legacy installer and a short blurb about how to get it.  It will improve the usefulness of this answer to future readers.  Feel free to use the info in comments, but make sure you add them to the answer as comments often get purged.

Following @arowswift I was getting errors like this : this port is already running....
So I had to do:
sudo port selfupdate    
sudo port -f activate gettext-runtime   
sudo port install python312 
sudo port select —-set python python312

